# How to write single test runner for classes with different @RunWith()?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito, test-runner

I wrote simple **method** that **executes** tests in my test classes: DataContainerTest.class, AnotherTest.class.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(DataContainerTest.class, AnotherTest.class);
        System.out.println(result.getRunCount());

        System.out.println("Total number of tests " + result.getRunCount());
        System.out.println("Total number of tests failed: " + result.getFailureCount());

        for(Failure failures : result.getFailures()){
            System.out.println(failures.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
```

This method **doesn't** work for my another class CommandsTest.class, where i'm using **annotation** `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`. See output below:

```
1
Total number of tests 1
Total number of tests failed: 1
No runnable methods
false
```

Here is the sample of the **CommandsTest.class**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Helper.class,
                UtilsPlatform.class,
                SessionManager.class,
                DataContainerTest.class,
                FieldObserver.class,
                android.util.Log.class})
public class CommandsTest {

    private static Commands2 commands;
    private static License mockedLicense;
    private static HSQL hsql;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpStatic() throws Exception {
        commands = new Commands2();

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(UtilsPlatform.class);
        PowerMockito.when(UtilsPlatform.isTablet()).thenReturn(true);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(android.util.Log.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FieldObserver.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(FieldObserver.class, "put", Mockito.anyInt(),
                Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.any(Session.class));

        hsql = PowerMockito.mock(HSQL.class);
        PowerMockito.when(hsql, "OnCaseOpen", Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(),
                Mockito.anyInt()).thenReturn(false);

        mockedLicense = PowerMockito.mock(License.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SessionManager.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Helper.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Helper.class, "writeToFile", Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.any(SocketException.class));
        PowerMockito.when(Helper.class, "getLicense").thenReturn(mockedLicense);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Helper.class, "fieldOpened", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
    }


    @Test
    public void sendKeyCombinationEventTest_nullParameters_returnOne(){
        Assert.assertEquals(1, commands.sendResponse());
    }

    @Test
    public void sendKeyCombinationEventTest_registredGuisNotNullAndOneIsLocal_returnOne(){
        Assert.assertEquals(1, commands.sendKeyCombinationEvent());
    }
```

While pressing **run button** in AndroidStudio, all tests are passed but my own TestRunner cannot run tests in this class.

Comment: Is this the output when you do `JUnitCore.runClasses(CommandsTest.class)`? If so, can you please show the class `CommandsTest`?

Comment: have already done :)

Comment: Looks like part of the code has been pasted twice. Can you fix it, please.

Comment: already fixed, don't know if you have checked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle classes using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation is just **put them into default test source** of your android project and then run all tests via `gradle test`. You don't actually need to write own test runner.